# How to store a lengthy json as a file and assign this json to a String variable?

Tags: java, json, servlets, jax-rs

I'm working on a server code which when API request is made should send a static Json as response.

- If Get on /root/, server return Json1
- If Get on /root/login/,  server return Json2

This Json1 and Json2 are static and doesnt change.I wanted to store these lengthy Jsons in a file and send them when API is invoked.Something like

```
 import javax.ws.rs.*;
    @GET
    public Response get(){
    String getres = "json1";
    return Response.ok().entity(getres).build()
    }
```

I dont want json1 to assign directly with double quotes in class since it will affect readability.I wanted to know how this json which is stored in a file can be assign to a variable and send that string as response.Is it better to have each json as a separate file like 1.json,2.json or is there anyother better way to have them all in single file.Please help.

Comment: What are you struggling with? Mapping different methods to different URIs? Reading a JSON file from the file system? Sending a raw JSON response? Question lacks focus.

Comment: Edited the question with more info.Please check

Answer (score 0):

You could put the files on the classpath (eg  `src/main/resources/foo.json` if building with maven). Then you could load via the classloader.

Eg

```java
ClassLoader loader = getClass().get Classloader();
InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("foo.json");
StreamingOutput stream = out -> {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int count;
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
};
return Response.ok(stream).build()
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I send this foo.json as the response without assigning to a String variable.

Comment: Updated my answer to use `StreamingOutput`. See [jax-rs-streaming-response](https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response)

Comment: Unfortunately ,transferTo doesnt seem to work .

Comment: `InputStream.transferTo(OutputStream)` was added recently to java. I've refactored to manually write the `InputStream` to the response `OutputStream`